# How to show only boundary box with more than 0.80 score in object detection yolov5?

Tags: python, yolov5

[image]

Following detection image, I'd like to show only 0.8-0.99.
I try to edit '''conf_thres=0.25''', '''iou_thres=0.45''' on detect.py but don't have any change output.

Please supporting me. How I show boundary box only 0.80 - 0.99 score and less than 0.80 score is not shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, you need to set the conf_thresh to 0.8 when you use the detect.py

Comment: Tank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

using the flag `--conf` when testing, and then put the number you want 0.8 in your case.
so, you will have something like this:

```
!python detect.py --weights models/best.pt --img 640 --conf 0.8 --source /path/to/test/images
```